# TS2339: Trouble with get access to property from fetch in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, next.js, recaptcha

I'm fighting with property **success** which is definited in API (recaptcha).

```
/**
   * The structure of response from the veirfy API is
   * {
   *  "success": true|false,
   *  "challenge_ts": timestamp,  // timestamp of the challenge load (ISO format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ)
   *  "hostname": string,         // the hostname of the site where the reCAPTCHA was solved
   *  "error-codes": [...]        // optional
    }
   */
```

Below I tried use optional chaining to fix that problem, but it does not work. I have tried use interface on different sides, but I can't fix that again with it.

Below code:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch"
//...
try {
const response = await fetch(
  `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${process.env.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRETKEY}&response=${captcha}`,
  {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    },
    method: "POST",
  }
);

const captchaValidation = await response.json();
if(captchaValidation?.success) // error: Property 'success' does not exist on type '{}'

} catch (error) {}
```

How can I get access to that property?

Comment: That's a typescript error. You have to tell TypeScript what "type" `captchaValidation` has, and therefor what properties are available.

Comment: I know that, but I have not idea how to implement that "type" to `captchaValidation` :/ Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem shat .json is not type aware and it returns Promis<never< - [.json method](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/main/%40types/index.d.ts#L139)

I can propose a solution you need to delcare the Captcha types and tell typescript *believe me it is this type*

```js
export interface CaptchaResponse {
  success: boolean;
  challenge_ts: string;
  hostname: string;     
  error-codes?: any[];
}


....
const rawResponse = await response.json();
// next line is nothing more just saying - believe me it is this type. It will not do type checking
const typedRespone = rawResponse as CaptchaResponse;
if(typedRespone.success)

....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface and declare that the response is that interface. Then TypeScript is told that a success property should exist.

```
export interface ApiResponse {
  success: boolean;
  challenge_ts: string;
  hostname: string;     
  error-codes?: any[];
}
```

Then declare it as that type:

```
const captchaValidation: ApiResponse = await response.json();
```

Comment: According to your second option I have got an error:
`Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ApiResponse'.`

The first option also throw an error: `Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'ApiResponse': success, challenge_ts, hostname`

Comment: Yeah wasn't sure which one should return your desired object, never mind the first line then. Seems TypeScript already knows your `await response.json()` returns `unknown` so then you could do type-casting like the other answer suggests.